# How to get key values with foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload, foreach

**The Problem:**

---

Hi! I'm making a file upload form where I can upload photos, I added `multiple=""` to the `input` and for the `name="upload_photo[]"` so I'm able to upload multiple files. When I print `$_FILES['upload_photo']` I get this and I want to get the `values` of each `key` with `foreach`.

So for example I want to get just `[name]` what will be `egg.jpg` and `green.jpg`.

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => egg.jpg
            [1] => green.jpg
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => image/jpeg
            [1] => image/jpeg
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php50E9.tmp
            [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php50EA.tmp
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24450
            [1] => 65030
        )

)
```

**This is what I have tried so far**

---

But this gives me everything I don't have control over it.

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'] as $keys => $file){

  foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'][$keys] as $key => $files){
   echo $files . "<br />";
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Wait, what? I'm confused.; why have you added `multiple=""` to the `<input>` if you don't seem to want multiple?

Comment: :D Man, I just shown a version where I've uploaded just one file, ok I will edit it :P

Comment: OMG!! :))) ... Check it out again, ahhh

Comment: Try to avoid nesting the same variables like this, it can get confusing, especially if you don't know *exactly* what scopes to where.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're trying to do, give this a shot:

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'] as $photo) {
    echo $photo['name'];
}
```

I don't know how your `$_FILES` array got structured like this, and it appears you changed your question since i first answered, as my solution worked for the way your question was originally posted.

So for the *new* array structure of `$_FILES` you'll have to use nested loops, like so:

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'] as $photo) {
    foreach($photo['name'] as $name) {
        echo $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The result : `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\includes\upload_photo.php on line 7` x5 , x5 because there are 5 keys.

Comment: I didn't changed my question, I just improved it to be more understandable :), I think this will work, I've made something similar right now, let me try it.

Comment: you changed the structure of the `$_FILES` array, which changes the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3418628/revisions

Comment: `I added multiple="" to the input and for the name="upload_photo[]" so I'm able to upload multiple files.` that was there in the original question too, just because I provided other values I didn't changed the structure of the array.

Comment: And I get an error what says that the index `name` doesn't exists , with your code.

Comment: This shouldn't work. When there are multiple files with the same name, `$_FILES` doesn't break `$_FILES["whatever"]` into an array of files, it makes the keys of it into arrays. So for instance, you wouldn't use  `$_FILES["whatever"][0]["name"]`, you'd use `$_FILES["whatever"]["name"][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'] as $key => $value)
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload_photo'][$key]); $i++)
   {
      echo $_FILES['upload_photo'][$key][$i];
   }

}
```

Not sure this is how I'd want to handle this situation, but I think it would work in your case.

edit: forgot the count

edit2:  If you know that your array contains the keys shown in the sample above, to receive all the values from just the `['name']` array, you'd do the follow:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload_photo']['name']); $i++)
{
   $name = $_FILES['upload_photo']['name'][$i];
   //do something else
}
```

OR

```
foreach ($_FILES['upload_photo']['name'] as $value)
{
   $name = $value;
   //do something else
}
```

As others have shown -

You seem to know the array keys involved / they are static, so the only thing left to do is figure out how many files there are - count the items inside the array and loop through it that many times.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is the idea to help you
when executing the following code with your given data in $_FILES it will print something like

> upload 1
>
> name = ...
>
> size = ...
>
> ---
>
> upload 2
>
> name = ...
>
> size = ...

```
$numUploads = count($_FILES['upload_photo']['name']);
for ($n = 0; $n < $numUploads; $n++) {

    echo 'upload ' . $n . '<br/>';
    foreach ($_FILES['upload_photo'] as $prop => $values) {

        echo $prop . ' = ' . $_FILES['upload_photo'][$prop][$n] . '<br/>';
    }

    echo '<hr/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me try it.

Comment: Hmm, and how should I get just the `name` or `tmp_name`? I need to specify a variable for them.

Comment: remove the inner loop and do something like

$currentFileName = $_FILES['upload_photo']['name'][$n];
$currentTempName = $_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name'][$n];

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is *JUST* the names of the uploaded files, then this will work:

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo']['name'] as $idx => $name) {
    echo "File #$idx: $name<br />"
}
```

If you're wanting to process each uploaded file, then you'd need something like this:

```
foreach(array_keys($_FILES['upload_photo']['name']) as $idx) {
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name'][$idx], '/some/where/on/your/server');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like $_FILES is weird. So to get the names, what you want is simply...

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo']['name'] AS $name) {
    echo $name . "<br />";
}
```

Or, based on my comment below, you could do...

```
foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'] AS $key => $file) {
    if ($key == 'name') {
        foreach($file AS $name) {
          echo $name . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but then I need to make a foreach for all of the keys! Are you sure that this is the best way? :S

Comment: Based on how the $_FILES array is designed, it appears so - you have to go through each key to get the information for each file, except (as would make more sense) if it were designed like `$_FILES['upload_photo'][0]['name']`. The only other way, really, would be to have a single loop like `foreach($_FILES['upload_photo'] AS $key => $file)`, and then check `if $key = "name"` in each iteration. Which, actually, if you combined it with a `switch` statement, might not be a bad way of going.

Comment: Also, in your question, you specified wanting just the `name`, so don't now turn around and say "but that only gets me the name!' ;)