# Can't upload files to Server folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file from a html form so that the file goes to a specific folder and the path get uploaded to a database. 
The database part works fine but the file doesnt go to my destination folder.
I have the folder permissions set to 777 and in my php.ini file, file_uploads = on.

```
<?php

require 'config.php';

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key => $name) {

   if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['name'][$key], '/upload_test/' . 
   $name)){
    echo "Uploaded";
} else {
    echo "Debug ", print_r($_FILES);
};

$path = '/upload_test/' . $name;

mysqli_query($connection, "insert into docs (path) values ('$path')");
}
?>
<script src="addInput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="dynamicInput">
        <input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple><input type="button" 
        value="+" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

When I try to upload it returns this:

```
Debug: Array(
     [upload] => Array(
        [name] => Array([0] => test.docx)
        [type] => Array([0] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)
        [tmp_name] => Array([0] => /tmp/phputnLek)
        [error] => Array([0] => 0)
        [size] => Array([0] => 12551)
    )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get key values with foreach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418628/how-to-get-key-values-with-foreach)

Comment: Is the upload directory really on the root of the file-system?

Comment: What do you mean by the root of the file system? All the files are within a folder /multiple_file_upload. There is the script. The upload folder is within that one so: /multiple_file_upload/upload_test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems that you are trying to upload to the wrong directory:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], '/upload_test/' . $name)) {
```

Note that the path `'/upload_test/' . $name` is on the root of your file-system as it starts with a slash `/`.

If you want to move the file to a directory relative to the one you are currently running the script from, you would need:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 'upload_test/' . $name)) {
                                                             ^ relative to the current path
```

As relative paths tend to lead to confusion, you can also set a variable to define the root of your web-site relative to the root of the file-system or use the value provide by php, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

For example:

```
define('WEBROOT', '/var/www/html');
...
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 
    WEBROOT . '/multiple_file_upload/upload_test/' . $name)) {
```

or:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/multiple_file_upload/upload_test/' . $name)) {
```

Comment: That Worked! It was a combination between your code and what @Klaus said!
Thanks guys!

Comment: @Serrano Yes, I missed the part about the `tmp_name`, I'll edit it in for completion.

Comment: @jereon what if instead of uploading directly to /upload_test i wanted to create a subfolder based on id from the database?

Comment: Nice robust answer. Not too small and not too big; *just right* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, Klaus deserves some of the credit though :-)

Comment: @jeroen call it a "team success" (effort) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Isn't it always ;-)

Comment: @jeroen when everyone's in the same ballpark and playing for the same team, *yes* ;-)

Comment: @Serrano That should not be a problem either, although I would add it to the filename instead.

Comment: Add the id to the filename? The thing is that the form is for multiple uploads. The user will upload multiple files i want to store all of the same user's files in the same folder. They would put in the name in the form then it would upload that name to the database, the database would generate an id and then php would create a folder with that id and then i would move files there. Is that doable?

Comment: @Serrano Sure, I don't see any problem, but if you run into a specific one, you should probably ask a new question here as it is a bit out of context of the current one.

Comment: @jeroen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46826678/file-upload-to-folder-created-based-on-id-from-database that it is. if you can help that would be amazing

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the temp-file to the new destination! In your case you´re trying to move the original filename to the destination folder.

This should do it ...

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$key], '/upload_test/' . $name);
```

Comment: Unfortunately  that didnt work. It has the same behavior.